# yFinance - Obtain all symbols

Tags: python, yfinance

Is there a way to grab all symbols available through yFinance (not yahoo finance)? Here's the package I'm referring to by ranaroussi: https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/

I've scanned the blog and blog comments, GitHub, some tutorials, and found no one mentioning a way to get a full list of symbols. I know there are other resources out there like JSON data or the ability to parse a csv but was curious if there was a way through yFinance. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you. :)

Comment: I have never seen that function before. The only way to do this is for you to make a string of all the issues concatenated with spaces somewhere and specify that to `yf.download(all_ticks,...)`.

Comment: If you find it or something similar, please share it here.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a selenium [solution](https://github.com/BloomShell/Seleniums/tree/main/yahoo-finance) which iterate all the pages of the screener which Yahoo finance gives us.

What the code does:

1. Initialize the ***Webdriver*** from `base.py`,
2. Goes into the webpage [screener](https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/new) url,
3. For each exchange ***(Nasdaq, Nyse, Bse)*** scrapes all available rows,
4. For each exchange a list of tuples is created; Each tuple has the name and the symbol of the row's company,
5. All list are saved as `.pkl`

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this](https://github.com/ahnazary/Finance/blob/master/finance/src/database/valid_tickers.csv) csv file. It contains over 30k stock symbols that have reports of their total revenue, free cash flow and total assets available to query through yfinance.

Also available in this csv file is the country of the companies with their report's currency on yahoo finance.